# What is the root view?

Tags: android

I need to pass the root view to a function in order to show a popup window

```
instructions_popup_window.showAtLocation( "parent view", Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
```

the problem is what to put as `"parent view"`.

In the `onCreate` I have

```
setContentView(R.layout.splash);
```

So is my root view: `"R.layout.splash"` or `"findViewById(R.layout.splash)"` or something else altogether?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root view is the topmost view in your splash layout.

You can give it an ID and then `findviewbyid` it OR you can get the activity's root view with this function:

```
getWindow().getDecorView()
```